# How to get drop down value on post back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, http-post, viewmodel

I have a view with a drop down, which is tied to the view model...

One of the view model's properties:

```
public int selectDTypeID { get; set; }
```

the view has a drop down:

```
   Html.DropDownListFor(
       model => model.selectDTypeID , 
       new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{ 
                   new { value = 1 , text = "Test1"  },
                   new { value = 2 , text = "Test2" },
                   new { value = 3 , text = "Test3"}
                },
              "value",
              "text"
       )
    )
```

How can I get the the value of the drop down list on post back without using an extra parameter... I'd just like to be able to do this...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContinueDonation(AddDonationViewModel model)
{
 var id = model.selectDTypeID;

}
```

Can I do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your View is a strongly typed view like this,

```
@model AddDonationViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(
       model => model.selectDTypeID , 
       new SelectList(
              new List<Object>{ 
                   new { value = 1 , text = "Test1"  },
                   new { value = 2 , text = "Test2" },
                   new { value = 3 , text = "Test3"}
                },
              "value",  "text"))    

    <input type="submit" value="go" />
}
```

When you click on submit, the selected value will be available in the SelectdTYpeID property in your HttpPost Action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContinueDonation(AddDonationViewModel model)
{
  var id = model.selectDTypeID;  // You have your selected ID here
}
```

Comment: how could I still perform a submit, but yet load the results into a div on the same page my jquery is something like $('#btnSelect').click(function() { $('#div').load('/Controller/ContinueDonation'...);   how could I make something like this work? (returning a partial view from the controller..)

Comment: @redBarron : Is it a new question ? Do you want to use a jquery form submit and show some content in the page ? pls provide more details. If it is not related to do this, i would encourage you to write a new question.